# PHP XMLRPC Requests Sending HTML Data in Request

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml-rpc

I am new to XMLRPC requests.
In some forums i have read that HTML Entities will be cleaned by XMLRPC.

I wanted to ask that is it possible to send HTML Data in RPC Request?

Thanks

Comment: Can you wrap the html in CDATA tags?

Answer (score 0):

XMLRPC works as any XML request so you just need to wrap your HTML code inside

```
<![CDATA[ ]]>
```

Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) for more info.